# Open source SQL connector for NoSQL (like MongoDB)

Tags: sql, mongodb, t-sql, nosql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sql query to mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615916/sql-query-to-mongodb)

I recently came across Quest data connector to do SQL queries with NoSQL database like MongoDB. However, i presume that it is just development use. Is there any open source connector that allows SQL queries to NoSQL db's? Most specifically to MongoDB.

Comment: So you wanna take out the sql injection protected and natural language of MongoDB queries and replace them with something for an entirely different tech and with entirely different....well nearly everything? I would say it would just be easier to learn how to query in MongoDB. However I know of none.

Comment: [Hibernate OGM](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/ogm.html) - JPA for NoSQL. See the other question.