# Pymongo equivalent of an SQL query

Tags: python, jquery, mongodb, pymongo

I'm new to MongoDB. I am trying to convert a SQL query to fetch the same results, but from a MongoDB database. The SQL query is as follows -
select count(country) as c, continent from world group by continent order by c desc;

Could someone please guide me with this?

My aggregate structure is - 
{
country: "China",
continent: "Asia"
}
{
country: "Sri Lanka",
continent: "Asia"
}
{
country: "USA",
continent: "NOrth America"
}

If I were to persist with this aggregate structure, could someone please explain how I could go about this?

TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this reference may be of use: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/sql-comparison/

But to specifically convert your SQL above (because it contained a count and and a group by)  I used this converter: https://klaus.dk/sqltomongodb/

```
db.world.find(  { country : { '$exists' : true } } ,{continent:1} ).count().sort( { c : -1 } )
```

Props to https://stackoverflow.com/a/14346168/1129926 for the link to the converter.