# How can I write This SQL Query in MongoDB Query?

Tags: mysql, mongodb

1.Here @xyz is variable
2.I need this Query in MongoDB

```
SELECT AdminUserID,AdminUserName,Email,ProfileImage,AU.IsActive,CreatedDt,LastUpdatedDt,AU.UserID,U.Username,U.Password
FROM AdminUser AS AU WITH(NOLOCK) LEFT JOIN [User] AS U ON U.UserID = AU.AdminUserUserID AND U.IsDeleted = 0  
WHERE AU.IsDeleted = 0  
    AND AU.IsActive = ISNULL(@IsActive, AU.IsActive)  
    AND AdminUserID = ISNULL(@AdminUserID, AdminUserID)  
    AND AdminUserName = ISNULL(@AdminUserName, AdminUserName)   
    AND AU.UserID=ISNULL(@UserID,AU.UserID)  
    AND ISNULL(AU.AdminUserUserID,'') = ISNULL(@AdminUserUserID,ISNULL(AU.AdminUserUserID,''))  
ORDER BY AdminUserName
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sql query to mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615916/sql-query-to-mongodb)

Comment: 1) this query would throw syntax error in mysql, it is more likely to have come from ms sql server. It is also missing the from clause. 2) mongodb works very differently from a relational database. Direct conversion often does not make any sense as you would ideally choose a different data structure to what you have in a relational database.

Comment: It's a from Stored procedure That's why syntax is diff and I have very big sp so i give just one query

Comment: Stored proc or not, this query would raise a syntax error in mysql.

Comment: Now edited i need just help in how to check AdminUserID = ISNULL(@AdminUserID, AdminUserID) condition in Mongo